# Appendix: "Appendix" not in ToC but in header

Tags: appendices

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{MyChapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Any appendix title}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I am not using `\appendix` because of the bug with `\include` (because in fact I am including all appendices and chapters). I like the default of this environment but I want to remove the "appendix" word in the toc (and only in the toc! I like it at within the appendix' header).

Currently:

```
Contents

1 MyChapter                       3 
Appendices                        5
Appendix A Any appendix title     7
```

Expected:

```
Contents

1 MyChapter                       3 
Appendices                        5
    A Any appendix title          7
    B ...
```

The indentation before `A` and `B` would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) According to the [`appendix` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf), the option `titletoc`:

> Adds a name (e.g., ‘Appendix’) before each appendix listed in the ToC

If you don't want it, don't use it.

b) You can indent the appendix entries with the package [`tocloft`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) by setting `\cftchapindent` to some reasonable value.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{MyChapter}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftchapindent}{3em}}
\chapter{Any appendix title}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a) Thanks for the hint to the option b) With this solution I have a problem. Please have a look at the expanded question :)

Comment: Hm, I really do not want to change the whole construct only for this one missing indent. Are there any other chances?

Comment: Split them up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476157/add-an-indent-to-appendix-line-in-toc-for-included-appendix

Comment: @S-Man Seen it...